# Using sessions in .net core 1

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to enable sessions in .net core webapp. I have tried following the documentation from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore1x). But issue is the sessions are not getting persisted. With every new request new session id is generated even if previous request has stored something in session. Also I don't see any cookie in dev tools.

[image]

Referenced dlls

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.1"
```

My startup file looks something like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); });

    // Add services needed for sessions
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });

    // Add in-memory distributed cache
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    // initialising other services, authentication and authorization policies
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // enable session before uisng it in pipeline
    app.UseSession();

    // setting custom user middleware
    app.UseUserMiddleware();

    // set up the mvc default route
    app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute("default", "myDefaultRoute"); });

    // adding few other middlewares

}
```

And I set and access the session values in my controller something like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private const string Key = "someKey";

    public async Task<ResponseModel> Get()
    {
        var id = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(Key);
        return new ResponseModel(await _myService.GetAsync(id));
    }

    public async Task Set([FromBody] RequestModel request)
    {
        var id = await _myService.GetAsync(request.id);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(Key, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: In dev tools are there any cookies in the response headers?

Comment: What is UseUserMiddleware? Do you still have a problem if you remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, session state is stored in distributed cache, which you've configured to be in-memory. This is basically the same as In Proc session storage in ASP.NET. Since everything stored in memory is tied to the process, whenever the process changes, your session store is wiped.

Now, it should still persist request to request, as long as you keep the application running, but particularly if you stop/start debugging in Visual Studio, you're killing and restarting the process and therefore, wiping the session.

Long and short, if you need your sessions to be persistent, you need to use a persistent store, like SQL Server or Redis. Either can be used in development just as well as in production, if you so desire. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed) for details on how to set up a persistent store.

Comment: @ChisPratt . The following statement looks incorrect to me
"In ASP.NET Core, session state is stored in distributed cache."
Asp.Net Core supports both type of caching: in memory as well as distributed cache. I think statement should be like following
"In ASP.NET Core, session state can be stored in distributed cache."

Comment: Session *always* uses distributed cache. There's an in-memory distributed cache provider for in-memory sessions.